# How can we print this output?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

```
String x = "1 -7 2";
String y = "-2 2 1";
```

Output:

```
1,-2
-7,2
2,1
```

We'll use x's first number which is negative or positive, y's first number ...

Comment: Those three languages are really different...

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and explain what is not working as you expect.

Comment: The magic comes with the split function...

Comment: Do you want help with C or Java or VB.net?

Comment: language doesn't matter, how can we write this algorithm's code ?

Comment: So use language-agnostic tag, not some random tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
String[] splitX = x.split(" ");
String[] splitY = y.split(" ");

System.out.println(splitX[0]+","+splitY[0]);
System.out.println(splitX[1]+","+splitY[1]);
System.out.println(splitX[2]+","+splitY[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use the Scanner class.

```
String integers = "1 -4 3";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(integers);
while(sc.hasNextInt())
{
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt();
}
```

Look it up in the javadocs :)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 1):

Just a rough sketch

- split both strings at white space into arrays
- loop over these two arrays and merge them one by one

Answer (score 1):

For Java:

You can split each of your strings using the split method and then you have an array of each that you can print out the corresponding characters from each array.

Answer (score 1):

In `java` use directly `split` function on space `" "`

In `c` use `strtok` on space `' '` and put those into 2 array of integers and just loop over it. for `odd` iterations first array for `even` iterations 2nd array and print those numbers

Answer (score 1):

This deals with cases where x and y are not of the same size

```
    String x = "1 -7 2";
    String y = "-2 2 1";

    // Split the strings
    String[] xSplit = x.split("\\s+");
    String[] ySplit = y.split("\\s+");

    // Loop through them
    for (int i = 0; i < xSplit.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(xSplit[i] + " ");

        if (i < ySplit.length)
            System.out.print(ySplit[i] + " ");
    }

    // Print more y if needed
    for (int i = xSplit.length; i < ySplit.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(ySplit[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

simple way to do it in C:

```
char * x = "1 -7 2";
char * y = "-2 2 1";
int xs[3], ys[3];

sscanf(x, "%d %d %d", xs, xs+1, xs+2);
sscanf(y, "%d %d %d", ys, ys+1, ys+2);

printf("%d, %d\n%d, %d\n%d, %d\n", xs[0], ys[0], xs[1], ys[1], xs[2], ys[2]);
```